# Strawberries from seed. Apparently growth stopped. is it fine?

Tags: strawberries

I planted strawberry seeds on coconut seed starters. The seedlings did come, and I got two nice set of round leaves (the cotyledons I guess) for each seed followed by a new pair of nice, real leaves. The seedlings grew to approx half a centimeter high, with the leaves being a little smaller than the length of a grain of rice. I was extremely happy about it but then I realized the growth stopped. It's like they are stable in that size since weeks. I keep the coconut starters wet from below, adding water to the base plate once every three days.

I am keeping the seedlings inside, on a front window. I receive very little sun. Is it the expected life cycle for the plant, or is it due to some problem ?

Answer (score 7):

Coconut husk doesn't have much in the way of nutrients; which makes it great for starting seeds on because they don't damp off as easily as soil grown seedlings, but it is probably time to either transplant into potting mix, or fertilize with some sort of gentle weekly type of liquid fertilizer if the seedlings aren't big enough, or you don't have a place to put them...

Great job on growing strawberries from fruit btw, I haven't ever had the patience. .